# C# HTML Font Tag Parsing

Tags: c#, parsing

I need to parse a large amount of text that uses HTML font tags for formatting,

For example:

```
<font face="fontname" ...>Some text</font>
```

Specifically, I need to determine which characters would be rendered using each font used in the text. I need to be able to handle stuff like font tags inside another font tag.

I need to use C# for this. Is there some sort of C# parser class to make this easier? Or would I have to write it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have not used it, but I have seen the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) frequently mentioned for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable to your situation as I don't know what the intended use is, but what about the use of XSLT tempaltes?

Comment: You are suggesting sending HTML into XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the HTML into Internet Explorer, and then query the DOM for font tags, (or CSS style).

Don't know if this is the best option performance wise.